# Convert Dictionary to ICollection in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Here I am stucked with the conversion of `dictionary` to `Icollection` in EF Core. I have `Dictionary` in `FlatEmployee` class in which I am storing list of key, value pair in database. I have declared like this:

```
public class FlatEmployee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, long> PayAndAllowances { get; set; }
}

//====================Configuration 
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FlatEmployee> builder)
{
        builder.HasKey(f => new { f.EmployeeId });
        builder.Property(sb => sb.PayAndAllowances)
            .HasConversion(
                pa => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pa),
                pa => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, long>>(pa));
}
```

This works absolutely fine when I am seeding or inserting. But the problem I am facing when I am trying to get the FlatEmployee class. This is because I want to get the dictionary in Collection. For that purpose I have declared another class like this:

```
public class LastPayCertificateViewModel: IHaveCustomMapping
{
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public EmployeeEarningDTO PayAndAllowances { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(Profile configuration)
    {
        configuration.CreateMap<FlatEmployee, LastPayCertificateViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.EmployeeCode , opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.EmployeeId ));
    }
}

public class EmployeeEarningDTO : IHaveCustomMapping
{
    public ICollection<BaseEmployeeDictionary> PayAndAllowances { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(Profile configuration)
    {
        configuration.CreateMap<FlatEmployee, EmployeeEarningDTO>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.PayAndAllowances, opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.PayAndAllowances));
    }
}

public class BaseEmployeeDictionary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Amount { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to use above classes for getting the data like this:

```
public class LastPayCertificateQuery : IRequest<LastPayCertificateViewModel>
{
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
}

public async Task<LastPayCertificateViewModel> Handle(LastPayCertificateQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{           
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<FlatEmployee>();
    predicate = predicate.Or(emp => emp.EmployeeId == request.EmployeeCode);
    var employee = await _context.FlatEmployee
                        .Where(predicate)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
    if (employee == null)
        return null;
    var empVM = _mapper.Map<LastPayCertificateViewModel>(employee);
}
```

Then I am getting null in `PayAndAllowances in empVM`. This is what my problem is. Where is my problem? I thought it was because that Dictionary has key value pair and which is not been able to convert to `BaseEmployeeDictionary`. I have tried this way as well to add List Item to `PayAndAllowances in empVM`

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, long> data in employee.DeductionsByAdjustment)
 {
     BaseEmployeeDictionary listItem = new BaseEmployeeDictionary
     {
         Name = data.Key,
         Amount = data.Value
     };
     empVM.EarningDetails.PayAndAllowances.Add(listItem);
     return empVM;
  }
```

Which of course wont work because the `empVM.EarningDetails.PayAndAllowances` is null and throws NullReferenceException. My queries is how to map between the Dictionary to ICollection while Creating Map in `EmployeeEarningDTO`. OR It would be really appretiated for your valuable suggestion and solution please.

Comment: I don't think EF Core supports such type of mapping. How is `FlatEmployee.PayAndAllowances` supposed to be stored in the corresponding database table?

Comment: It is storing data like this `{"Basic Pay":10000,"DA":20000,"HRA":10000}`

Comment: JSON? In a text column? It's interesting to see how that works at all (e.g. inserting data). Are you using `ValueConverter`? Please show the fluent configuration of `FlatEmployee` entity - all other code you've posted in irrelevant if EF Core can't read `FlatEmployee` objects with `PayAndAllowances` populated from database.

Comment: I have updated the question with `FlatEmployee` Configuration.

Comment: Thanks. EF Core reads it w/o a problem, so it turns out to be the opposite of my previous comment :) - AutoMapper mapping issue.

Comment: Can you please direct me in correct direction.. How to solve AutoMapper mapping issue here with the code snippet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be AutoMapper mapping issue.

First, `EmployeeEarningDTO` inside `LastPayCertificateViewModel` creates additional level compared to `FlatEmployee`:

```
LastPayCertificateViewModel.PayPayAndAllowances.PayAndAllowances
```

vs

```
FlatEmployee.PayAndAllowances
```

AutoMapper maps by default properties with the same name. So inside `FlatEmployee` to `LastPayCertificateViewModel` map it would try to map `Dictionary<string, long> PayAndAllowances` to `EmployeeEarningDTO PayAndAllowances`. But there is no mapping from `Dictionary<string, long>` to `EmployeeEarningDTO`. Instead, there is a mapping from `FlatEmployee` to `EmployeeEarningDTO`, so you have to tell AM to use it:

```
configuration.CreateMap<FlatEmployee, LastPayCertificateViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.EmployeeCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.EmployeeId))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.PayAndAllowances, opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity)); // <--
```

Second, mapping from `FlatEmployee` to `EmployeeEarningDTO` - AM will automatically try to map `PayAndAllowances` properties, but there is no mapping from `KeyValuePair<string, long>` to `BaseEmployeeDictionary`. You could define such mapping

```
configuration.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, long>, BaseEmployeeDictionary>()
                        .ForMember(dst => dst.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key))
                        .ForMember(dst => dst.Amount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

which will allow you to use simply

```
configuration.CreateMap<FlatEmployee, EmployeeEarningDTO>();
```

however you probably won't do that because you don't want *every* `KeyValuePair<string, long>` to be mapped to `BaseEmployeeDictionary`, so you could do that mapping inplace:

```
configuration.CreateMap<FlatEmployee, EmployeeEarningDTO>()
     .ForMember(dto => dto.PayAndAllowances, opt => opt.MapFrom(entity => entity.PayAndAllowances
        .Select(src => new BaseEmployeeDictionary { Name = src.Key, Amount = src.Value })));
```

Comment: Exactly the problem was with the auto mapper. Thank you so much it solved my problem.